# Where the missing_index_[number] come from

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have just tried to do one view from my table and when I was looking for missing indexes, I found some created indexes which nobody has created. Do you know what could create them ? I'm using C#, ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework with edmx model creation

Comment: [link] https://imgur.com/k0Y1cRf

Comment: Review this document to identify your missing_indexes: https://dotnetvibes.com/2017/08/23/identifying-missing-indexes-in-sql-server/

Comment: What do you mean with "created indexes which nobody has created"? Somebody had to create them, where does that database structure come from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure nobody has created indices, they might have been created automatically by SQL Server [Automatic tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning?view=sql-server-2017) (feature is supported by SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL).

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning) states, automatic tuning options is able to:

> CREATE INDEX - Identifies indexes that may improve performance of your
>   workload, creates indexes, and automatically verifies that performance
>   of queries has improved.

There is good thread on subject in [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43772/why-dont-databases-create-their-own-indexes-automatically)